# NoSuchMethodError: The setter 'employeeId=' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy haciendo un llamado a mi api en localhost recibo bien la respuesta de la api, estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de asignar esa respuesta que recibo de la api a una variable de UserModel, no se porque me dice que la estoy llamando como nula a la variable si en teoria estoy asignandole un valor que recibo desde la api

la clase Usuario provider, recibe dos parametros para hacer la peticion a la api

```
    class UsuarioProvider {
  final _prefs = new PreferenciasUsuario();
  Future<UserModel> login(String email, String passowrd) async {
    UserModel userModel;
    final Map map = {'username': email, 'password': passowrd};

    final resp = await http.post(
      '${utils.urlApi}/User/authenticate',
      body: json.encode(map),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    );
    Map<String, dynamic> decodedResp = json.decode(resp.body);
    print(decodedResp);
    if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
      userModel.employeeId = decodedResp['employee']['id'].toString(); // aqui especificamente lo tengo al error
      userModel.id = decodedResp['id'].toString();
      userModel.username = decodedResp['username'];
      userModel.role = decodedResp['role'];
      userModel.employeeId= decodedResp['employee']['id'];
      userModel.blocked = decodedResp['employee']['isDeleted'];

      return userModel;
    }
```

mi modelo:

```
import 'dart:convert';

UserModel userModelFromJson(String str) => UserModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userModelToJson(UserModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UserModel {
  UserModel(
      {this.employeeId,
      this.username,
      this.password,
      this.oldPassword,
      this.token,
      this.passwordHash,
      this.passwordSalt,
      this.role,
      this.id,
      this.blocked,
      this.message});

  String employeeId;
  String username;
  String password;
  String oldPassword;
  String token;
  String passwordHash;
  String passwordSalt;
  String role;
  String id;
  bool blocked;
  String message;
  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
        employeeId: json["employeeId"],
        username: json["username"],
        password: json["password"],
        oldPassword: json["oldPassword"],
        token: json["token"],
        passwordHash: json["passwordHash"],
        passwordSalt: json["passwordSalt"],
        role: json["role"],
        id: json["id"],
        blocked: json["blocked"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "employeeId": employeeId,
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
        "oldPassword": oldPassword,
        "token": token,
        "passwordHash": passwordHash,
        "passwordSalt": passwordSalt,
        "role": role,
        "id": id,
        "blocked": blocked,
      };
}
```

No uso el metodo fromJson porque la respuesta es una lista de map, y tengo que "navegar" entre la respuesta para poder asignar la respuesta recibida, agradezco si me podrian dar una mano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta instanciar el objeto, ahí el error te dice que al asignar `employeeId` se encontró con un nulo.

Instancia/Crea el objeto antes de asignarle un valor.

```dart
if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
      userModel.employeeId
```

Debería quedar con

```dart
if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
      userModel = UserModel();
      userModel.employeeId
```

O mejor aún, como mencionas que ya tienes tu modelo y veo que ya tienes un método para crear el objeto, quedaría así:

```dart
    Map<String, dynamic> decodedResp = json.decode(resp.body);
    print(decodedResp);
    if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
      userModel = UserModel.fromJson(decodedResp);
      return userModel;
    }
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder Diego, si efectivamente me faltaba la instancia del objeto, no puedo votar la respuesta porque aun no tengo 15 de reputacion :c

Comment: :(  márcala como resuelta, creo que eso si se puede

Comment: Listo Diego ahi esta ;)